# Which tool is most suitable for cutting thick cardboard with ease?

Tags: cardboard

I have a big scissor but cutting very thick cardboards like  tv case  in different shapes like butterfly wings consume too much effort.

What kind of tool will make my life easy w.r.t very thick cardboards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My preferred tool for heavy card is the classic [Stanley 99](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stanley-99E-Retractable-Blade-Knife/dp/9820372690) knife.  The blade is slightly stiffer than those of the snap-off craft knives, and the metal handle is good and solid.

If you do go for a snap-off knife, for heavy card stick to one that takes 18 mm or even the rare 25 mm blades, rather than 9 mm blades, which are too flexible (but great for finer work on thin card).  The cheapest of these 18 mm and 9 mm knives are rather flimsy and don't latch very well, so it's worth buying a good one (probably sold singly rather than in a big pack).

You should buy plenty of blades, as card can blunt them fairly quickly and a blunt blade tears the workpiece more easily than a new blade.

Comment: Can you edit in the need for a good base to work on, (as a good knife will cut into the table top and so on.)

Comment: @Willeke the question [was asked today](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/5484/319) and cutting heavy card can be done unsupported (especially when starting with boxes as in the question, so sticking to an appropriate tool rather than advising on technique was deliberate.

Comment: I have done a lot of cardboard cutting and seen it done by others at work. The table tops have to be replaced often for most of them.

Comment: @Willeke I don't disagree with that, I was just trying to resist the urge to be overly broad in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Since Chris has properly covered our misplaced-answers from the comments, I will offer some high end solutions...

Laser cutters, industrial strength vinyl cutters and picture-framing mat-cutters are all good options for working with heavy cardboard.  Scroll saws and Band saws can also work.  See if you have a makerspace or fablab in your area where tools like these are usually available.