# What tool is available for protecting the box cutter and the surface of the table while using box cutter?

Tags: tool-selection, cardboard

[Which tool is most suitable for cutting thick cardboard with ease?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/which-tool-is-most-suitable-for-cutting-thick-cardboard-with-ease#comment6242_5483)

> The tool you are looking for is called a box cutter which is just a razor blade in a handle. ***Make sure to put something uncuttable under the cardboard before slicing it with the blade or you will ruin your work surface, tabletop or floors***.

What tool is available for keeping under the cardboards by which we can prevent the damage to box cutter and the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cutting mats](https://www.hobbycraft.co.uk/craft-essentials/craft-tools/cutting-mats) are avilable in a wide range of sizes.  I have A4 and A5, but even A1 (59.4 x 84.1 cm or 23.3 x 33.1 inches) aren't expensive at around £/$/€20. They provide a reasonably non-slip surface (Link is to a UK shop, just happens to have a range on one page).

If you want even bigger, a layer or two of vinyl flooring can work in the short term, but you will get through that with a craft knife eventually, so its best mounted on scrapwood.

Another large, cheap option is hardboard (masonite), but it will blunt the blade faster than a proper cutting mat.  MDF is worse still, but either of these can be useful if you have a few very long cuts to make.